# Unity 2D GameObject(s) Rotate Randomly

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good evening everyone,

I hate to ask this question but I am new to Unity and I'm running into an error(I think) that is really unexpected. I actually just started work on my first 2D game tonight and cannot find anything online that seems to explain this.

Long story short, I have a character (GameObject) that simply moves from the left to the right on a platform, then he should fall (or jump) onto the next platform and keep moving until he falls into infinity. I have been able to get my character to move from the left to the right, but when he reaches the midway point between the two platforms ... the platforms begin to rotate counter-clockwise. I'm including screenshots below to show what I mean. Has anyone seen this before?

My player has the RigidBody2D and Box Collider 2D Components
My platforms have the Box Collider 2D Components

This is the code I am using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
public Rigidbody2D rb;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(1, rb.velocity.y);

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 10);
    }
}
}
```

and these are the photos of the game as it plays out:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your game isn't the character but the platforms!

On each platform you have a Rigidbody2D and a box collider 2D so the player can walk on them and collide.

On unity physics is always working and so even if you set the gravity to zero the player has gravity and so it will push the platforms and make them rotate

You can easily fix this by going to the **constraints** of the rigidbody2D of each platform and check the **freeze rotation** on the Z axis. It will stop rotating

Comment: I actually locked the Z axis on the player and it totally worked! I would have never thought of that! THANK YOU SO MUCH! People like you make learning game development fun. Again, thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually the platforms don't move...

But you have connect the camera Transform to the player transform; So when the play rotation changed(When he falls) The camera rotation changed with the player too

You can fix this issue by making the camera follow the player position via code, [This video could help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jTY11Am0Ig)

Comment: I really wish I could mark two answers as correct because your answer was basically half the issue and that video will come in so useful later. If I can mark two answers correct please let me know. Like I told the gentleman above, I would have never thought of this! THANK YOU SO MUCH AS WELL! People like you make learning game development fun. Again, thank you, thank you, thank you! (and if you know how to mark two answers correct please let me know as I want to make sure you get credit too).